# jquery to run clone function with multiple selectors

Tags: jquery, clone

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add_file_group, .clone_email2, .clone_email").click(function() {
        $("#clone_file_group").clone().insertAfter("div#clone_file_group:last");
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```

Using this  function with different selectors in one section, just one selector is working

Comment: Can you show the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your class name `clone_email2, .clone_email` suggest that these are generated dynamically. So you need to use [**delegate event handler**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Try this

```
 $(document).on('click', '.add_file_group, .clone_email2, .clone_email', function () { 

       $("#clone_file_group").clone().insertAfter("div#clone_file_group:last");

    });
```

> **Description:** Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a
>   specific set of root elements.

Comment: @Muzamil301 : great that I could help !